# Could not load file or assembly exeption

Tags: c#, sql-server, dll, server, smo

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I'm trying to access it with C# by using Server Management Objects (SMO). I have installed required dll files via Nuget package manager.

However, whenever I try to run my application, it enters a break state and throws the following exception:

[image: Screenshot of the exeption]

I have tried to solve this issue by installing `SharedManagementObjects.msi` and `SQLSysClrTypes_amd64.msi` files for SQL Server 2014, and even for other versions just to be sure, however, nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is with the assembly SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version ***14***.100.0.0?

Not sure but I would say that the version numbers 12.0.0.0 and 14.100.0.0 refers to Sql Server versions:

- SQL Server 2014      --> version 12
- SQL Server 2017/vNext (?)  --> version 14 - not out yet!

So that indicates you have a mix with different dll versions.